# return xml node that do not have specific child elements

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, linq-to-xml, xmldocument

I have the following code which is returning all nodes and thier values.
I only want to return nodes that do no have certain child nodes.
MY code base I am working from is

```
  XmlNodeList nodelist = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//DAV:schemata/DAV:classschema[@name='Tapestry']/DAV:propschema/DAV:*", nsmgr);
            foreach (XmlNode node in nodelist)
            {
                strNode = node.Name;
                strValue = node.InnerText;
                responseString += strNode + " " + strValue + "\r\n ";          
            }
            return responseString;
```

So I only what to return /propschema/* if the /propschema/ child does not contain a certain child node. For my example i do not want to return the propshema node if there is a child node of  or

I had though I should be using something like

```
XmlNodeList nodelist = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//DAV:schemata/DAV:classschema[@name='Tapestry']/DAV:propschema/DAV:*[not (count[system>0])", nsmgr);
```

But that is failing with an error of invalid token
'//DAV:schemata/DAV:classschema[@name='Tapestry']/DAV:propschema/DAV:*[not (count[system>0])' has an invalid token.

What am I doing wrong here? Am I missing syntax, "", or something else?

I have determined that if I can use a filter in the XPATH I would be applying it at the wrong point.
I want to return all propschema nodes and thier children except if the proschema had a child node of . So I need to put the filer earlier

```
  XmlNodeList nodelist = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//DAV:schemata/DAV:classschema[@name='Tapestry']/DAV:propschema[filter for system]/DAV:*", nsmgr);
```

But whenever I try to use a 'not' or type of filter I get a token error.

Is it possible to filter directly in the XPATH?

Comment: have you looked at the property : `HasChildNodes` ?

Comment: I had not, never saw an example. I have now tried .../DAV:propschema/DAV:*[not (hasChildNodes = system)]" with the same result as if it were not there at all.

Comment: So can I actually use a filter of not in an xpath statement

Comment: `/DAV:propschema[not(DAV:*)]`

Comment: @Alex your a champ. I had been trying all combinations of the not filtering but was not using the DEV namespace prefix. You are a champion. +1.